# Popup after user has been idle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some code that brings up a message for the user to either ignore the message or go to another page if they have been idle for more than a minute. Everything works, as I want it to except when the user ignores the message. Here is my code:

```
if ( valid ) {
    var idleTime = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000);
});

function resetTimer() {
    idleTime = 0;
}

jQuery(document)
.on('mousemove', resetTimer)
.on('keydown', resetTimer)
.on('scroll', resetTimer);

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime >= 1) {
        jQuery('#popup').show();
    }
    jQuery(window).unbind();
}

jQuery('#popupClose').click(function() {
    jQuery('#popup').hide();
});
}
```

I want the popup to not repopulate after they click #popupClose.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use `clearInterval()` when the user clicks that element?

Comment: Working fiddle/plunkr would be nice

Comment: clearInterval(idleInterval); this will remove the interval so it does not happen again

Comment: Ya, I guess, I've been trying to figure out what I need to call I've tried return, jQuery(window).unbind, and doing general searches to figure it out with nothing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the information in a cookie, or with a flag (depending on whether you want the popup on each pageview or only once, period).

Then, check the flag/cookie before the showing of the popup. For example:

```
function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime >= 1) {
        if (jQuery('#popup').data('closed') == 1){
            jQuery('#popup').show();
        } 
    }
    jQuery(window).unbind();
}

jQuery('#popupClose').click(function() {
    jQuery('#popup').data('closed', 1);
    jQuery('#popup').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this. Just define a start time when you initialize your script. Let an interval run that checks how much time has passed. If it's more than your time wished show the dialog. if not hide it. Also reset the timer on your events.
Your javascript will look like this

```
$('#btclose').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(interv);
  $('#popup').hide();
});
var start = new Date();

var interv = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
  console.log()
  if(now-start > 5*1000){
    $('#popup').show();
  }

},10);


$('body').on('mousedown click mousemove', function(){
    start = new Date();
});
```

Here's my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/c2L7wpn3/8/

Seems to work. Let me know if this helps